# uploading php brings out pop up box?

Tags: php, upload

i just uploaded my php file to my new server, i want to check the file in my web browser, instead of showing the page, a pop up box saying you want to download the php file. what deos that mean? :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your web server is not properly configured to interpret PHP files.  It does not know what to do with the file and assumes you want to download it.

Web server configuration would be out of scope for Stack Overflow, so I won't go any further.